# the dimensional reduction issues in self-organizing map (SOM)

Tags: data-mining, neural-network, self-organizing-maps

Self organizing map is claimed to be able to visualize/cluster the high-dimensional data on a smaller dimensional space.  I have some difficulties in understanding this statement.

Consider a six-dimensional data set, the codebook vector/reference vector is also of six-dimensional.  According to the SOM algorithm, updating these reference vectors are also conducted in the six-dimensional vector space. If we are considering a two dimensional map, how should I understand the map between the six-dimensional data space and two-dimensional map space?

Comment: "....difficulties in understanding this statement." Suppose you have an image whose array is a 512x512 and you run it on a 16x16 SOM, the results will be that:512x512 is 'reduced' to the smaller 16x16. The high-dim data is 'clustered' to be the smaller dim. From here then, try the mathematical process as others have suggested.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The map between the N-dimensional input space and the 2D SOM space is a [non-linear projection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_transformation) preserving as much of the topology as possible.
It means that information about distance and angle is lost in the process but that proximity relationship between points is preserved (i.e. 2 points which are close one to another in the input space should be close in the SOM space).
I got my best insight in "what does a SOM do?" by using it on the [3D RGB color space](http://www.ai-junkie.com/ann/som/som1.html): the work of the SOM can easily be visualized in this case and should help to grasp the concept.

Answer (score 1):

The 2D self organizing map (SOM) distributes the input vectors onto a 2D plane. Mathematically the SOM is a 3D matrix and the length of the third dimension is given by the length of your input data. To visualize the SOM it's usual to compute the U-matrix. The U-matrix gives for each neuron of the SOM the mean Euclidean distance between the considered neuron and its neighbors.
[image: U-matrix]
The resulting 2D matrix allows the visualization of the high dimensional space onto a 2D plane. The high values give barrier between clusters represented as deep blue valleys in the following figure:
[image: U-matrix_example]
This U-matrix comes from the learning on this 3D data set:
[image]
And here the U-matrix in the 3D original space:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

You cannot understand it but it's possible to use it so you can try to think of it as a discrete function that can map for example a 4d vector space to a 1d vector. Most important is that your function is some sort of recursion. A L-system for example uses recursion or repetition a lot. A better description about monster curves can be found here at Nick' spatial index hilbert curve blog.